# Benei Menashe Jews

Tags: halacha, conversion-to-judaism, shevatim-12-tribes

A group of people from the North-East of India claimed to be the descendants of the lost tribe of Menashe. It was confirmed in 2005 by Rabbi Shlomo Amar Shlit"a, the then Sefardic chief Rabbi of Israel. They still go through a process of conversion for about 2-3 months (see [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bnei_Menashe)).

What is the halakha for lost tribes? Do they need to do "Tikkun haMiddot"?

Comment: Because a person in the process of normal conversion does not observe shabbat

Comment: @ezra I think the question is real. Are people undergoing giur lechumrah considered as full Jews, therefore subject to all of halacha, or as converts, therefore forbidden to respect Shabbat.

Comment: related: [How is giyur le’chumra different from a standard conversion in practice?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/25851/11501)

Comment: related: [How does a giyur lchumra differ from a regular conversion?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/31181/11501)

Comment: Before finding what I think is a duplicate, I noticed that it is not at all clear that Bnei Menashe only need a *giyur lechumra*, at least two sources ([here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shavei_Israel#cite_ref-10) and [here](https://yeranenyaakov.blogspot.com/2006/11/rav-amar-no-proof-bnei-menashe-are.html)) indicate the need for a full conversion. The rest of the question remains valid but was already asked

Comment: This thing is getting very much interesting. If only this question could go up to the concerned halachic Authority, which would be, I think,  The sefardic chief rabbinate of israel.